# Adding ReactOS Entry to GRUB2

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

So I have Windows XP and Linux Mint installed on a harddrive. I just finished installing ReactOS and it didnt show up in the Grub boot menu. I booted Linux Mint and ran the command sudo update-grub. But it didn't detect the reactOS install. So I need to know how to add it manually. Any help will be appreceated.
Thanks in advance.